# Как передать информацию об изменении в таблице JTable

Tags: java, swing

Задача: если значение в любой ячейке таблицы изменилось, необходимо вывести текст из базы данных.

```
public class WeekTasksPanel extends JPanel implements TableModelListener {
   private WeekTaskTable stdList;
   private JLabel lblCount = new JLabel();

   public WeekTasksPanel() {
      stdList = new WeekTaskTable();
      stdList.setModel(new TaskTableModel(...));
      stdList.getModel().addTableModelListener(this);
      ...
      lblCount.setText("Вывод текста");
      ...
   }

   @Override
   public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent arg0) {
       // Совершаем действия
       System.out.println("Hello");
   }

}

//Класс с моделью для таблицы
public class TaskTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
   public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
      ...
      fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
   }
}
```

Вопрос: Подскажите как можно передать информацию из TaskTableModel в WeekTasksPanel о том, что ячейка таблицы изменилась либо таблица была обновлена? Понимаю, что надо использовать Listener'ы, но в силу отсутствия опыта не понимаю как.

UPD: Код изменён на рабочий.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*TableModel* позволяет задать *Listener*, который будет оповещаться при изменении данных.

Следовательно, класс который должен оповещаться об изменениях должен реализовать интерфейс *TableModelListener* и в методе *tableChanged(TableModelEvent e)* производить необходимые операции при наступлении события.

Чтобы подписать этот класс на оповещения от модели, используйте *TableModel.addTableModelListener(TableModelListener l)*.

UPDATE1: Для принудительного запуска события в модели есть ряд методов *AbstractTableModel.fire**.

UPDATE2: Даже пример нашелся вашего случая http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался с Вашей помощью!

Comment: Рад помочь